# copy folder from server to local machine in ubuntu

Tags: copy, directory, ubuntu-14.04

I have a folder in my server and I tried to copy it in my local machine like:

```
scp my_username@remotehost.com:/path/to/some_folder /my/local/directory
```

Inside some_folder there is a folder that I want to copy.
When I run this command it says

```
/path/to/some_folder/: not a regular file
```

How can I copy a folder from server to my local machine.
I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `-r` flag on the [scp command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

```
scp -r my_username@remotehost.com:/path/to/some_folder /my/local/directory
```

From the manual page:

> -r' Recursively copy entire directories. Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal

Comment: -r it recursively copies the files .

Answer (score 4):

Easy way, but you need to understand it first. I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
To copy a complete folder with children's from **Sever to Local Machine**

Just go to local machine empty folder directory. Like my is "results" folder contain on desktop

**-r ==** copy entire folder with all flies

**khawar ==** Username on server Machine

**223.120.314.49 ==** Server IP address

**-P ==** Port

**22 ==** Port Number

**/data1/khawar1/lpr/Plate_Recognition-LPRnet/ ==** Complete directory address of server machine folder that you want to copy

**results ==** folder in local machine

```html
scp -r -P 22 khawar@223.120.314.49:/data1/khawar1/lpr/Plate_Recognition-LPRnet/ results
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the most interactive way is using *sftp*; you can manipulate the remote server as of your local machine. Let's say you have the following credentials for your remote server:

. **Username**: root

. **ip**: 185.48.22.23

*1. Step one:* Open your file explorer of your *ubuntu* local machine

*2. Step two:* Navigate to '*other locations*'

*3. Step three:* Insert your credentials with *sftp* on the '*Connect to server*' box and press 'connect'.

[image]